# VSCode doesn't acknowledge $refs component type when Vue script is imported as separate file with vue-class-component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-class-components

When a "*.vue" file is separated into different files, i.e.: `<script lang="ts" src="./x/script.ts">` VSCode throws an error; however, the `serve` script does not. There is no problem with compilation. The error is about the `$refs` property. VSCode does not recognize the registered component's properties:
`Property 'sideBarVisibilityChange' does not exist on type 'Vue'.`.

When declaring `$refs` inside the script tag as SFC component like this:

```js
$refs!: {
    sideBarComponent: SideBar;
};
```

Then accessing the SideBar component inside a method:

```js
this.$refs.sideBarComponent.sideBarVisibilityChange(newState);
```

Everything works fine as long as the code is an SFC. It "breaks" when the script is imported. The error comes only in VSCode, meaning when I run `npm run serve` (`vue-cli-service serve`) I get no errors! However, I get this inside the VSCode `Problems` window: `Property 'sideBarVisibilityChange' does not exist on type 'Vue'.` ts(2339).

**My setup**: VSCode, Vue + TypeScript, vue-class-component, vue-property-decorator.

The component is imported. It is declared as a `ref` inside the template. 
Here's some more code if you want to take a look: https://gist.github.com/JakubKoralewski/9d11bbb9535a96356466b37745630f8f

Or a whole repo to play around with that I'm currently working on:
https://github.com/JakubKoralewski/dziennik_php_frontend/tree/class-components

There are some errors I'm currently working on. They're not specific to this problem.

What's very weird is that when I try to follow the link from the Vue file to the script by clicking on the path I get this weird error:

```
Unable to open 'script.ts': File not found (file:///f:/f:/<path>/src/views/Authorized.vue/Authorized/script.ts).
```

It doesn't work to get VSCode to open the file path even if I do this stupid thing that is I import the script like this `<script lang="ts" src="../Authorized/script.ts"></script>` which is logically absurd, but displays the proper path when the error happens. Exactly, it still happens. Which means the error is the `f:/f:/` part. I thought it was a VSCode quirk and the filepath would actually be correct, but when I try to create a file like VSCode suggests I get another error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'f:\f:'
```

However, this does not seem to be the problem, because I supplied the whole absolute path for the file making the follow link work, but this changes nothing.

Here's an error VSCode throws in the Developer Console:

```
Error: Tree element not found: {
    "resource": "/f:/<path>/src/views/Authorized/script.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2339",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property 'sideBarVisibilityChange' does not exist on type 'Vue'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 142,
    "startColumn": 31,
    "endLineNumber": 142,
    "endColumn": 54
}
    at s.getElementLocation (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:89:591)
    at s.expandTo (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:89:187)
    at $.reveal (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:925:744)
    at W.revealMarkersForCurrentActiveEditor (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4487:161)
    at W.autoReveal (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4486:961)
    at W.onActiveEditorChanged (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4484:350)
    at W._register.e (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:4483:360)
    at d.fire (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:73:436)
    at setTimeout (file:///F:/PROGRAMY/VS Code/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js:69:969)
```